# Angular2 unit test service with Http call in constructor

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am struggling to unit test Angular2 service which has async Http call in the constructor (now I wonder should it be here in the first place).

Example code below - the mocked call never seems to have been executed and I am not sure where should I put it in. The test fails as the property I am asserting is undefined at the time of execution. I tried with fakeAsync and tick() but that didnt work neither.

Service class:

```
    @Injectable
    export class Service {

      private data: any; //some object that will be returned from server

      constructor(private http: Http) {
                    this.http.get('url')
                      .map( (res: Response) => res.json())
                      .subscribe(res => this.data = res);
                  }
      getId() {
         return data.id;
      }

    }
```

The unit test:

```
describe('service test...', () => {

    let service: Service;
    let backend: MockBackend;
    let result = { id: 123 };

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpModule],
            providers: [
                Service,
                {
                    provide: Http,
                    useFactory: (mockBackend, options) => {
                        return new Http(mockBackend, options);
                    },
                    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
                },
                MockBackend,
                BaseRequestOptions
            ]
        });

    });

    beforeEach(inject([Service, MockBackend], (s, mb) => {
        service = s;
        backend = mb;

        backend.connections.subscribe((conn) => {
            conn.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: result})));
        });
    }));

    describe('test...', () => {

        it('should have id of 123...', async(() => {
            expect(service.getId()).toEqual(123);
        }));

    });

});
```

Comment: @AngularFrance This is a service tho.

Comment: My bad, I was a little too quick to respond... So you want to test just the service? (not a component injecting the service). In that case why do you bother setting up a module with `TestBed.configureTestingModule`? A service is just a class. As long as you set up its dependencies correctly, it doesn't need a module to run. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html for a code example. The problem with your setup might be that the service under test is never instantiated.